# TryResizeView doesn`t work and always return false

Tags: c#, uwp

I am create few `ApplicationView` and save them id's to `List<int>`. When I try resize views TryResizeView() return false, sometimes its resize main window.

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(id);
    bool res = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(700, 700));
}
```

When I am create windows I set minimum size 300.

Comment: With so little to go on my first two questions would be, are you sure that the view is resizable and are you running this code on the UI thread?

Comment: @ChrisBD 1. Can the `ApplicationView` not be resizable?
2. Yes, code calling in code behind - it`s UI thread.

Comment: I tried call TryResizeView in SecondaryPage page, it could work, can you tell which page  you call above method on ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, I call in MainPage

Comment: You should call it in the SecondaryPage  page. or `GetForCurrentView`  will not retrieve correct ApplicationView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TryResizeView doesn`t work and always return false

I'm afraid you can't call resize method to resize SecondaryPage from main window. You should call it in the SecondaryPage page. and then `GetForCurrentView` will retrieve correct ApplicationView instance.

If you do want to show custom size window, the better way is [show multiple views with AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window), and it has `RequestSize` method that could [initialize specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#request-window-size-and-placement) window size you want.

```
colorPickerAppWindow.RequestSize(new Size(300, 428));
```

And here is [official code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/AppWindow) that you could refer to.